# Problema con Datatable al cargar un Json en forma dinámica

Tags: javascript, html5, json, datatables

Lo que estoy haciendo es seleccionar distintos archivos Json con un select. Una vez que el usuario selecciona uno de los archivos se debería desplegar el datatable en la tabla de datos. **Funciona**, pero si quiero cargar otro archivo no despliega los datos a pesar que en la consola se vé claramente que existe la carga. Si refresco la página y seleccione un archivo distinto que el anterior al refresco, se carga correctamente.

Es decir el problema no es de la carga de datos, si no del refresco del datatables. Buscando en el manual de [datatables](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax) (la parte de Ajax)  y en el foro, pero no he logrado dar con una solución al problema. He utilizado dos formas distintas de carga, pero nada:

HTML:

```
    <select id="fechas">
        <option value="0">Seleccione una fecha</option>
        <option value="01012019.js">01-01-2019</option>
        <option value="01022019.js">01-02-2019</option>
    </select>

    <table id="dataTable">
         <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Fecha - Hora</th>                    
              <th>Valor Máximo</th>
              <th>Valor Mínimo</th>
              <th>Diferencia</th>                  
            </tr>
          </thead>
   </table>
```

JS Intento 1

```
$('#fechas').on('change', function(){    
    desplegarDatos(this.value);        
});

 
  function desplegarDatos( url ){

      $.getJSON(url , function(data) {
      var tabla = $('#dataTable').dataTable({
        "aaData": data,
        "aoColumns": [
                { "mDataProp": "Archivo" },
                { "mDataProp": "Maximo" },
                { "mDataProp": "Minimo" },
                { "mDataProp": "Diferencia" }
           
            ],
                paging: false,
                searching: false,
                retrieve: true
        });
     }); 

  }
```

JS Intento 2

```
$('#fechas').on('change', function(){    
    desplegarDatos(this.value);        
});

function desplegarDatos( url ){

$.ajax({
      
        type: "GET",
        url: url ,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (obj, textstatus) {
                console.log(obj) // La consola arroja los json de forma correcta (o el uno o el otro)
                var tabla = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
                    data: obj,
                    columns: [
                        { data: 'Archivo' },
                        { data: 'Maximo' }, 
                        { data: 'Minimo' },
                        { data: 'Diferencia' }
                    ],
                    paging: false,
                    searching: false,                    
                    destroy: true,
                    serverSide: false,
                    processing: true,
                    retrieve: true
                });
            
        
        },
        error: function (obj, textstatus) {
            alert(obj.msg);
        }
    });
  }
```

Ambos funcionan pero solo la primera vez, si cambio el select por otro archivo, no lo recarga. Intenté con ajax.reload() en distintos lados del script, pero tampoco me resulta

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente necesitas alguna de estas dos optiones serverSide set to True si vas a user AJAX a bDestroy to re-generar la tabla cuando la data cambie.

```
  bDestroy : true,
  serverSide: true,
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero serverSide debe estar en False ya que se está trabajando por el lado del cliente no del servidor. Si lo dejas en True te arroja un error. Por otro lado ya intenté con  destroy: true (Ver JS Intento 2) pero no funciona.

Comment: si el serverSide es opcional no estaba seguro si querias usar AJAX, utiliza bDestroy en cambio de destroy el nombre es importante

Comment: tambien puedes usar  tabla.draw(); https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()

Comment: Seguí atentamente la documentación de tabla.draw() y no me resultó. Intenté también como me indicaste bDestroy y tampoco lo extraño que al ponerle un console.log(obj) se ve claramente que los array son distintos pero no se despliegan....

Comment: Aca hay un ejemplo funcionando de: https://jsfiddle.net/8obafymc/30/

Comment: Lo replique y funciona , cambie los datos duros por json en archivos y ya no funciona. me pasaron un dato que hoy voy a probar tengo que re inicializar el dataTable con la API $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#tabla') (parece que aquí el usuario lo soluciona con el // fake server)

Comment: No necesitas usar Jquery ajax datatable trae incluido AJAX intentan usando  solo datatable con el metodo AJAX.